# How to integrate HikariCP and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, hikaricp

I'm trying to use HikariCP. My project used `Spring-Boot`, `MyBatis`, database is SQL Server. I found a demo but it's using MySQL. I want to know the `dataSourceClassName` of SQL Server.

Here is the demo:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${mysql.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mysql.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="700000"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="600000"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dataSourceClassName">
                com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
            </prop>
            <prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</prop>
            <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</prop>
            <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As you can see the `dataSourceClassName` is MySQL. Where can I get all the other database's class name?

Answer (score 2):

I found it on [GitHub](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). SQL Server is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`